# How to get function value in main sub VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to get the value (The regex result) of the function below inside my main sub in orde to add it to the title of my file, how can I do this ?

```
    Public Sub Process_SAU(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim object_attachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String

Dim Code as String
Code = ExtractText


' Folder location when I want to save my file
saveFolder = "C:\Users\gdeange1\Desktop\suggestion updates\UpdateBusinessInformation\Processed_By_Bulks"
       For Each object_attachment In Item.Attachments
' Criteria to save .doc files only
    If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".json") Then
 
        object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & Code & "_" & object_attachment.DisplayName

    End If
 
    Next

End Sub

Function ExtractText(Str As String) ' As String
 Dim regEx As New RegExp
 Dim NumMatches As MatchCollection
 Dim M As Match

 regEx.Pattern = "((.*))[A-Z]{0}(Danièle Loubert|Véronique Mantha|Julie-Emmanuelle Carle|Nicolas Bertrand|Martine Jean)"

 Set NumMatches = regEx.Execute(Str)
 If NumMatches.Count = 0 Then
      ExtractText = "Blabla"
 Else
 Set M = NumMatches(0)
     ExtractText = M.SubMatches(0)
 End If
    Code = ExtractText
 End Function
```

The code I tried above did not work.

Thank's for your help!

Comment: What string are you passing to the function? `ExtractText` expects an input string, what is it?

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? It's essential that you specify this.

Comment: @BigBen I'm trying to get the value of the regex match (list of person names), example: I found "Daniel Loubert" inside an email thanks to the regex part and I want to store this value in the file name just after the date (in the sub).

Comment: `Code = ExtractText` is incomplete because you need to pass `ExtractText` the `Item.Body` presumably.

Comment: `Code = ExtractText` within the function body looks suspect as well.

Comment: I used the function found in this post : https://www.slipstick.com/developer/regex-parse-message-text/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass `Item` to `Public Sub Process_SAU(Item As MailItem)`.

Similarly, you have to pass `Str` to `Function ExtractText(Str As String) As String`.

```vb
Option Explicit 

Private Sub test_Process_SAU()

    Dim currItem As Object
    
    ' with a selected item
    Set currItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    
    ' or
    
    ' with an open item
    'Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    
    If currItem.Class = olMail Then
        Process_SAU currItem
    End If
    
End Sub


Public Sub Process_SAU(Item As MailItem)

    Dim Code As String
    
    ' Pass the applicable string to the function
    Code = ExtractText(Item.body)
    Debug.Print " Code: " & Code
    
    Dim object_attachment As outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String

    saveFolder = "C:\Users\gdeange1\Desktop\suggestion updates\UpdateBusinessInformation\Processed_By_Bulks"
    
    For Each object_attachment In Item.Attachments
        
        If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".json") Then
 
            object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & Code & "_" & object_attachment.DisplayName
            
        End If
 
    Next

End Sub


Function ExtractText(Str As String) As String

    Dim regEx As New regExp
    Dim NumMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim M As Match
    
    regEx.Pattern = "((.*))[A-Z]{0}(Danièle Loubert|Véronique Mantha|Julie-Emmanuelle Carle|Nicolas Bertrand|Martine Jean)"
    
    Set NumMatches = regEx.Execute(Str)
    If NumMatches.count = 0 Then
        ExtractText = "Blabla"
    Else
        Set M = NumMatches(0)
        ExtractText = M.Value
    End If
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have copied the function `ExtractText(Str As String)` , but this function expects a string value to be passed while using this function, which you are missing. If you pass a string type value while using the function in your main code, it should work.