# Getting email addresses of recipients, and those in the CC list through VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have functioning code I copied somewhere online that extracts certain details from each email.

Can the code be modified to include the email addresses of recipients and those in the CC list as well?

```vb
Sub FetchEmailData()

Dim appOutlook As Object
Dim olNs As Object
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olItem As Object
Dim iRow As Integer

' Get/create Outlook Application
On Error Resume Next
Set appOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If appOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set olNs = appOutlook.getnamespace("MAPI")
'Set olFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 == Inbox for some reason

Set olFolder = olNs.session.PickFolder

' Clear
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Delete

' Build headings:
Range("A1:E1") = Array("From:", "To:", "CC:", "Date", "SenderEmailAddress")

For iRow = 1 To olFolder.items.Count
    Cells(iRow + 1, 1) = olFolder.items.Item(iRow).Sender
    Cells(iRow + 1, 2) = olFolder.items.Item(iRow).To
    Cells(iRow + 1, 3) = olFolder.items.Item(iRow).CC
    Cells(iRow + 1, 4) = olFolder.items.Item(iRow).receivedtime
        
    If olFolder.items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
        Cells(iRow + 1, 5) = olFolder.items.Item(iRow).Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
    Else
        On Error Resume Next

        Cells(iRow + 1, 5) = olFolder.items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
    End If
        
Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you extract email addresses from the 'To' field in outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641704/how-do-you-extract-email-addresses-from-the-to-field-in-outlook)

Comment: Hi niton, I tried all the codes there but couldn't get them to work. I couldn't find the macros for some of the scripts, while others had a "Object Required" error when there was a line that contained "item.recipients"

Comment: You cannot run code that requires input, directly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66361210/how-to-get-function-value-in-main-sub-vba

Comment: I see, so looking at the code by Tragamor in the thread linked in your first reply, do I have to place my mail folder in a certain part of the code? Because when I just try to call the code through Alt+F8, I get "Argument not optional"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demonstrates how you might apply one of the possible answers in
[How do you extract email addresses from the 'To' field in outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641704/how-do-you-extract-email-addresses-from-the-to-field-in-outlook).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FetchEmailData_Call_smtpAddress()

Dim appOutlook As Object
Dim olNs As Object
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olItem As Object

Dim iRow As Long

' Get/create Outlook Application
On Error Resume Next
Set appOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If appOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set olNs = appOutlook.getnamespace("MAPI")

Set olFolder = olNs.PickFolder

If olFolder Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "User cancelled."
    Exit Sub
End If

' Clear
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Delete
    
' Build headings:
Range("A1:E1") = Array("From:", "To:", "CC:", "Date", "SenderEmailAddress")

For iRow = 1 To olFolder.items.Count
        
    Set olItem = olFolder.items.Item(iRow)
        
    With olItem
        
        Cells(iRow + 1, 1) = .Sender
        Cells(iRow + 1, 2) = .To
        Cells(iRow + 1, 3) = .CC
        Cells(iRow + 1, 4) = .receivedtime
            
        If olFolder.items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
            Cells(iRow + 1, 5) = .Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            Cells(iRow + 1, 5) = .SenderEmailAddress
            On Error GoTo 0 ' consider mandatory
        End If
            
        ' Pass the item to smtpAddress
        smtpAddress olItem
        ' You could move the smtpAddress code into the main sub.
        ' Entering the email addresses in the next empty cells in the row, should be easier.
        
    End With
        
Next iRow
    
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit

Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub


Private Sub smtpAddress(ByVal Item As Object)

    ' https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642193/1571407

    Dim addrRecips As Object    ' Outlook.Recipients
    Dim addrRecip As Object     ' Outlook.Recipient
    Dim pa As Object            ' Outlook.propertyAccessor

    ' This URL cannot be clicked nor pasted into a browser.
    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
    Set addrRecips = Item.Recipients

    For Each addrRecip In addrRecips
        Set pa = addrRecip.PropertyAccessor
        Debug.Print pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I think the Microsoft code will not work anymore since the schema is invalid, according to the thread you had linked

Comment: What gives that comment any credibility? That commenter probably clicked on the non-clickable URL or pasted it into a browser.

Comment: Understandable. I got a code successfully running thanks to your help! However, I was wondering why there were some emails missing from the output, as compared to if I manually exported the emails from Outlook itself (via Import & Export Wizard)?

Comment: Post a new question with the code, example data, the expected result and the result.

Comment: Noted, I have just posted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Recipients` property to get all recipients of a particular mail item in Outlook. The [Recipient.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.type) property returns or sets a long representing the type of recipient. For mail items values are shown in the [OlMailRecipientType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmailrecipienttype):

- `olBCC` - 3 - The recipient is specified in the `BCC` property of the Item.
- `olCC` - 2 - The recipient is specified in the `CC` property of the Item.
- `olOriginator` - 0 - `Originator` (sender) of the Item.
- `olTo` - 1 - The recipient is specified in the `To` property of the Item.

So, you may find the a Recipient object which corresponds to the CC field and use the [Recipient.AddressEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.addressentry) property which returns the `AddressEntry` object corresponding to the resolved recipient.

```
Set myAddressEntry = myRecipient.AddressEntry
```

The [AddressEntry.Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.address) property returns or sets a string representing the email address of the `AddressEntry`. In case of Exchange accounts you may use the [AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser) method which returns an `ExchangeUser` object that represents the `AddressEntry` if the `AddressEntry` belongs to an Exchange `AddressList` object such as the Global Address List (GAL) and corresponds to an Exchange user. In that case the [ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.primarysmtpaddress) property returns a string representing the primary Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) address for the `ExchangeUser`.

You may find the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article helpful.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for the reply! Sorry but I am not really sure how to proceed forward with those information, can you kindly advise what I should add to the current code?